# Plotshape on Stochastic RSI - (Pine script beginner)

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to use plotshape funtion on Stockastic RSI ( K ) to be attached (on) and move with the K line.
But there is something wrong with the code and ploting is away from the K line ( top or bottom). I want it to stock with the K line.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic RSI", shorttitle="Stoch RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

Cross1 = k<20
Cross2 = k>80
plotshape(Cross1 , "dots", style=shape.circle, location = location.bottom )
plotshape(Cross2 , "dots", style=shape.circle, location = location.top )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `location = location.bottom` and `location = location.top`, that's why.

You should use `location = location.absolute` and then pass `k` as your `series` value.

```
plotshape(Cross1 ? k : na, "dots", style=shape.circle, location = location.absolute)
```